# How to fix the pattern-matching exhaustive warning?

Tags: list, scala, pattern-matching, scala-collections

Some scala code:

```
val list = List(Some("aaa"), Some("bbb"), None, ...)

list.filter(_!=None).map {
  case Some(x) => x + "!!!"
  // I don't want to handle `None` case since they are not possible
  // case None
}
```

When I run it, the compiler complains:

```
<console>:9: warning: match may not be exhaustive.
It would fail on the following input: None
                  list.filter(_!=None).map {
                                   ^
res0: List[String] = List(aaa!!!, bbb!!!)
```

How to fix that warning without providing the `case None` line?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are using `map` after `filter`, you may to use `collect`.

```
list collect { case Some(x) => x + "!!!" }
```

Comment: map expects function, collect expects partial function which fits the requirement.

Answer (score 3):

you can use `flatten`

```
scala> val list = List(Some("aaa"), Some("bbb"), None).flatten
list: List[String] = List(aaa, bbb)

scala> list.map {
     |   x => x + "!!!" 
     | }
res1: List[String] = List(aaa!!!, bbb!!!)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`@unchecked`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.unchecked) annotation, although that requires some additional code:

```
list.filter(_!=None).map { x => ( x : @unchecked) match {
  case Some(x) => x + "!!!"
 }
}
```

Comment: Does @unchecked really seem like the best way? It removes a compiler warning but can add confusion for future developers maintaining it

Comment: Given the other answers this option is probably not the best way in this situation, but there could be other situations in which it is warranted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`get`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Option@get:A) method instead of pattern matching.
 Here is example code:

```
scala> val list = List(Some("aaa"), Some("bbb"), None)
list: List[Option[String]] = List(Some(aaa), Some(bbb), None)
scala> list.filter(_ != None).map(_.get + "!!!")
res0: List[String] = List(aaa!!!, bbb!!!)
```

Answer (score 0):

some other way to solve this issue, without `filter` and `pattern matching`

```
scala> list.flatten map (_ + "!!!")
```

or

```
scala> list.flatMap (_ map (_ + "!!!"))
```